# How to trigger operator inside Python function using Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have the following code:

```
def chunck_import(**kwargs):
    ...
    for i in range(1, num_pages + 1):
        start = lower +  chunks * i
        end = start + chunks
        if i>1:
             start = start + 1
        logging.info(start, end)
        if end > max_current:
            end = max_current
        where = 'where orders_id between {0} and {1}'.format(start,end)
        logging.info(where)
        import_orders_products_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id='import_orders_and_upload_to_storage_orders_products_{}'.format(i),
            mysql_conn_id='mysql_con',
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_con',
            provide_context=True,
            approx_max_file_size_bytes = 100000000, #100MB per file
            sql = 'import_orders.sql',
            params={'WHERE': where},
            bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
            filename=file_name_orders_products,
            dag=dag)

    start_task_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)

    chunck_import_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='chunck_import',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=chunck_import,
        dag=dag)

    start_task_op >>  chunck_import_op
```

This code uses `PythonOperator` to calculate how many runs I need from the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` and create the `WHERE` cluster of the SQL then it needs to execute it.

The problem is that the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` isn't being executed.

I can't actually do

```
chunck_import_op >> import_orders_products_op
```

How can I make the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` be executed inside the `PythonOperator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think at the end of your for loop, you'll want to call `import_orders_products_op.execute(context=kwargs)` possibly preceded by `import_orders_products_op.pre_execute(context=kwargs)`. This is a bit complicated in that it skips the `render_templates()` call of the `task_instance`, and actually if you instead made a `task_instance` to put each of these tasks in, you could call `run` or `_raw_run_task` instead but these both require information from the dagrun (which you can get in the python callable's context like `kwargs['dag_run']`)

Looking at what you've passed to the operators it looks like **as is** you'll need the templating step to load the `import_orders.sql` file and fill in the `WHERE` parameter. Alternatively it's okay within the callable itself to load the file into a string, replace the `{{ params.WHERE }}` part (and any others) manually without Jinja2 (or you could spend time to figure out the right jinja2 calls), and then set the `import_orders_products_op.sql=the_string_you_loaded` before calling `import_orders_products_op.pre_execute(context=kwargs)` and `import_orders_products_op.execute(context=kwargs)`.

Comment: I get error:  TypeError: pre_execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_execution_date'

Comment: @Programmer120 sorry I wasn't sure how to pass in the context. Given that python callable should get a single arg 'context' which is a dict, if you make the callable's signature `**kwargs`, then all the dict keypairs will be in `kwargs`, which I think is what you should assign `context` to.

Comment: @dlamblin any idea why we need pre_execute()? Can we not just use execute() directly?

Comment: @Programmer120  I am not able to render the template when I use execute() Any help?